# How can analyze single file in sonar eclipse plugin?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, sonarqube

posible do that in sonar eclipse plugin?
currently I see only can analyze project.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the other way round. Instead of specifying which file to analyse, you can exclude unwanted files/folders using various configurations available in SonarQube.

Details available here: http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analysis+Parameters